# Vectorized String Distance

Tags: pandas, preprocessing, numpy, distance

I am looking for a way to calculate the string distance between two Pandas dataframe columns in a vectorized way. I tried distance and textdistance libraries but they require to use df.apply which is incredibly slow. Do you know any way to have a string distance using only column operations ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using cosine similarity on a bag of words representation of the strings.

Comment: Thanks @Oxbowerce. Though, it's not ideal because I am measuring distances between email adresses, so the order of letters matters to me.

Comment: If you use n-grams (e.g. sequences of 4 characters) instead of single characters for the bag of words representation you should still be able to take into account the order of the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here that performance across string distance libraries varies greatly : https://github.com/life4/textdistance#benchmarks

The python-Levenshtein library is lightning fast compared to the others so I will use this one. If it's not sufficient I will use parallelism as suggested by @Peter

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and tried parallel computing using `joblib`. In terms of performance this approach seems okay. However, it appears that `joblib` "blocks" RAM memory when repeated very often. So I'm open for alternatives (or suggestions how to terminate the parallel job properly).

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import distance
import pandas as pd
# https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html

# Define some distance measure
def calc_dist(myrow):
    return distance.levenshtein(myrow[0], myrow[1])

# Some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({
     "text1":["some text","foo","bar","new text","more words"], 
     "text2":["text","hello","bar","bar","move words"]})

# Columns to lists / zip them 
l1=df['text1'].tolist()
l2=df['text2'].tolist()
nlist = list(zip(l1,l2))

# Calculate distances
dist_vec = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(calc_dist)(i) for i in nlist)

print(dist_vec)
> [5, 4, 0, 8, 1]
```